# Como ponerle hover a un a:before

Tags: css, hover

Tengo un icono en un menú de navegación. Para poner el icono le he puesto font-size 0px y he utilizado esta regla para poner el icono.

```
.menu li:first-child a:before {
  color: white!important;
  content: "\f015";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Y me gustaría ponerle un hover a ese before he intentado lo siguiente pero no funciona.

```
.menu li:first-child a::before:hover {
  color:#da001c;
}
```

Y también

```
.menu li:first-child a:hover:before {
  color:#da001c;
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con ```a:hover::before```?

Comment: si, pero eso elimina el color de a:before que tengo (cuando no es hover)

Answer (score 0):

No se puede poner `:hover` sobre un after o un before, pero sí se puede hacer sobre el elemento original y el hover incluirá tanto al after como al before.

```
.menu li:first-child a:hover {
  color:#da001c;
}
```